# Facebook graph api Topics and Interests

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if Topics are the same as Interests?

Also whats the difference between 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adTargetingCategory&class=interests&access_token=abcd

and

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=blahblah&class=demographics&access_token=abcd

I knwo that the second one gives topics/interests related to the given keyword.
Whats the first one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question, the first API call returns all interests (tipically used to build a 'browse interests' feature), and the second one is a search by keyword.